# Is there a way I can export or access my photoshop Custom Shapes Library in illustrator

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I've been trying to export my Photoshop CC custom shapes library into Illustrator, all in one, go rather than individually pasting them into Illustrator. I guess similar to loading and saving effects files. Can this be done?

Comment: Could you possibly please state what you tried, so we know what hasn't worked for you?  For example, have you tried copy to copy and paste a custom shape you have drawn in Photoshop into Illustrator?  Is there some reason this does not work for you?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I had a family emergency. Thanks for replying. I was trying to export all my premade custom shape files at one time rather than individually. I guess similar to loading and saving effects files.

Comment: I have edited your question, and added that extra information since it will be important if someone is going to answer.

Comment: Yes you could write a loop in jsx and save them individually

Answer (score 1):

Photoshop custom shapes are saved in .csh files, which are only usable in Photoshop.  Illustrator doesn't recognise the format.

I guess what you could do is place all the custom shapes, one at a time, in a Photoshop document, and using the Path Selection tool, select all the paths, paste them into a new Illustrator document, and apply a fill to all the shapes.  Then save that document, then as you need them just copy and paste into any Illustrator document. Or even select each shape and turn it into a symbol.